# CakePHP - How do you tell a controller's action to output a raw image header?

Tags: php, cakephp, image-processing, controller

I'm recoding an existing project by using the CakePHP framework. Now, in my existing code I have a PHP file (just called thumb.php) which takes a file and the size and yields a resized raw image to the browser. This can then be utilized in for instance an image tag or for other purposes. This "thumbs.php" file just uses a header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); to output a raw image.

Anyway, here it is in action:
http://www.dosspirit.net/php/thumb.php?file=268-transport-tycoon-deluxe-3.png&size=640

*(You can change the size parameter to like 240 or even 1240 and the image will be resized for you).*

**Now, I want to replicate this behaviour in cakephp.**

So far, I have this setup:

```
class ScreenshotController extends AppController {
    public function view() {
        (Some code to handle image scaling)
    }
}
```

Looking at the above code, urls to a screenshot would be like this: http://www.domain/screenshot/view/268-transport-tycoon-deluxe-3.png/640

Now, how can I tell a controller in cakePHP to output the image header instead of going through a view etc., hence mimicing the functionality from the thumbs.php file ?

Any response is appreciated,

sincerely,
- bakkelun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's still PHP in CakePHP. You can do the same thing in your action:

```
public function view() {
    header('…');
    echo $imageData;
    exit();
}
```

Having said that, you should use the [`Controller::header`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-Controllerheader) method to output raw headers (for overrideable unit tests). Even better, you should use [Media Views](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1094/Media-Views) to output images the Cake Way (which requires you to write to a file though).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Yes, there's still "plain php", but I wanted the "cake way". Writing to a file is "ok" I guess if you'd want caching, but what outputting just the image data?

Comment: @bakkelun As I wrote, you can simply `echo` the image data (or call `imagejpeg` or whatever you want to do), then `exit()`. It'll output just like any other PHP script.